# Getting Connection timeout error when application is idle

Tags: java, datasource

when ever I keep my application idle for 10 or 15 hours, I will get Connection time out error. But when I frequently use my application then I couldn't able to see this error any time. Could any one please guide me whether I am making some thing wrong in the below code. This application is used by only two users and that too be not frequently.

```
<Context path="/****" reloadable="true">
       <Resource
            name="XXXX"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            username="XXXX"
            password="XXXX"
            driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
            maxIdle="4"
            maxWait="30000"
            initialSize="2"
            url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;database=XXXX"
            maxActive="20"/>


</Context>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is not so much information given in your example. Assumed that is a small piece of a Spring (Spring Framework) context configuration, i would prefer to configure a connection pooling for the database. This pool can hold an amount of idle connections for each request an can open new ones if no connection is available in the pool for the current request. I found this piece of XML in the MySql documentation.

```
<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close"
  class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${db.jdbcurl}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="3"/> 
</bean>
```

Please be aware that the datasource is of type `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource`. For further information please refer to the Documentation of [MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-spring-config-connpooling.html), [Spring Framework](http://spring.io/docs/reference) and [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/)

Comment: Thanks Dangermouse

Comment: You're welcome. If any answer met your requirements, please rate it and/or mark it as accepted to help others with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on information provided on question, i can see:

1. Most probably, application is not properly handling `connection` i.e. it is creating connection, but then somehow failed to close connection properly in application code.

   As per question, if only 2 users are using this app then probably you might not able to catch connection exhausted error which usually thrown when connection pool reaches max limit.

But if you increase app users  you will see your connection reached max limit very quickly.

Check number of connections that got created after application starts and observe behavior. Check if inactive connections are getting closed or not.

2. Also, I don't see `inactive connection timeout property` in configuration. Can you check if you have this property.

Comment: Thanks Ashish for the explanation.

Comment: Ashish, can I use the parameter removeAbandoned="true" in the above configuration.Setting this to true can recover db connections from applications that fail to close a connection. whether it will work?

Comment: yes, you can try using this. Moreover please check if you can use `removeAbandonedTimeout` along with this, which checks for timeout in seconds before abandoned connection can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with databases, it gets shutdown/locked up after a long idle period. In MySQL it is 8 hours by default. You have to use a connection pooling library like C3P0 which has configuration to talk to database and turn on the connection if it is closed.

It is possible to increase the timeout amount in databases, but not recommended. Therefor go for a system like I mentioned above which can turn on the connection for you.